# Radical of an ideal in the polynomial ring with reducible generators

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

To find the radical of an ideal can be a very complicate task. Considering ideals in the polynomial ring, I am wondering if this task can be simplified in the case the generators of the ideal have the form $L_1 L_2...L_m$ with $L_1,\dots,L_m$ linear polynomials.

Comment: It is always possible to find a set of generators in that form (if the dimension of the algebraic set is zero), but the problem is to find  it. Let me state in this way, the ideal is defined by those generators, which are known.

Comment: I doubt it helps much, but I guess you know that the components of the variety are linear subspaces, defined by one factor from each ideal generator. After discarding duplicated or embedded components, the problem is to intersect a bunch of ideals of linear subspaces. There is the [Derksen-Sidman theorem on regularity](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109035) that implies the reduced ideal of a union of $d$ linear subspaces (this is the radical you're looking for) is generated in degrees less than or equal to $d$. But I don't know how much that helps. Arrangements can be very complicated.

Comment: @ZachTeitler , I have a question. It seems to me that the radical of the ideal generated by products of linear forms is also generated by products of linear forms. In particular, this should be true if the subspaces is zero-dimensional. In the meantime, I found this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401373 
where there is written that not every arrangement has a radical ideal generated by products of linear forms. They give 5 points in general position in $P^2$ as an example. I checked this example and I found something different, the generators in that form exist.

Comment: I am extremely skeptical. For the case of 5 points in general position in the plane, the ideal is generated by a conic and two cubics, and the conic is unique (up to a scalar factor). For points in general position, it's an irreducible conic, and then it's not a product of linear forms. - The ideal of those points has a reduction generated by products of linear forms, meaning, there's a nonreduced scheme supported on those points with a linear-product generated ideal. But the radical of that ideal has the irreducible conic.

Comment: I had a look at this thesis
https://people.math.ethz.ch/~pink/Theses/2015-Bachelor-Paul-Steinmann.pdf
In section 5.10 there is an algorithm computing the radical of an ideal with finite codimension. If the ideal is of a finite number of points in general position, the  codimension is finite. Starting from an ideal generated by products of linear forms, one ends up with a radical in the same form. I dont see what is the problem, it seems that there is a contradiction with your reasoning, which looks correct.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, I see a problem with the proof that five points cannot have a radical ideal generated by products of linear forms. The fact that the conic is irreducible does not mean that you cannot write it as $P_1 g_1+P_2 g_2+\dots$, were $g_i$ are products of linear forms. $g_i$ should have at least degree $3$, but they can generate a polynomials of second degree.
Example:
$\prod_{k=1}^5 (x-x_k)$,
$\prod_{k=1}^5 (y-y_k)$,
$\prod_{k=1}^5 (x+y-x_k-y_k)$,
$\prod_{k=1}^5 (x-y-x_k+y_k)$,

They generate a radical ideal and have $5$ points in the affine space and no point at the infinity.

Comment: I thought you were talking about 5 points in the projective plane. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the argument on the unique conic, we were on different grounds.  One could say that generators as products of linear form generate every element of the ideal up to a factor $a^k$, with $a$ a fixed linear form (provided that the subapaces are points). Thanks a lot.